# Multiple rows in table not showing

Tags: android, tablerow

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = null;

    while (i < 5) {
        TableRow trow = new TableRow(this);

        while (j < 3) {
            tv = new TextView(this);

            tv.setText(" " + j + i);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setWidth(25);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            trow.addView(tv);
            j++;
        }
        Log.i("SS", "adding row for " + i + " time");
        this.addContentView(trow, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        i++;
    }
```

Hi,i m new to android.
I want to show 5 rows with 3 textview each.It seems simple but the above code is not working.It shows only one row with 3 textviews.In xml i m not using table layout ,the rows are being added to a linear layout only.Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the row into the tableLayout.

1) http://droidcake.com/2010/12/24/table-layout-tutorial/

2) http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout

3) http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=307

few tutorial to follow.

Comment: i add table layout in xml but don't define any tablerow tag in it as i dont know the no. of rows i would need. Dynamically rows are not inflating still only one row shows.